# How to translate android intent to flutter

Tags: android, flutter, groovy

I am trying to invoke and android app with certain perameters, can someone please assist me by trying to convert the following code into flutter, I am using the Android Intent flutter package but not having much luck.

Below is the code that i am trying to convert from Native android / Groovy to flutter

```
val launchIntent = Intent()
launchIntent.action = "CenDroid"
launchIntent.putExtra("Operation", "Sale")
// Get the time
val millisecond: Long = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()
val timeString = milliseconds.toString()
launchIntent.putExtra("Time", timeString)
launchIntent.putExtra("Caller", "Caller Name")
// InvocationKey is Sha512 of Sha256 of Sha1 of whatever is sent in the Time field.
var hashed = HashUtils.sha1(timeString)
hashed = HashUtils.sha256(hashed)
hashed = HashUtils.sha512(hashed)
launchIntent.putExtra("InvocationKey", hashed)
launchIntent.putExtra("Amount", 100.0F)
launchIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
startActivityForResult(launchIntent, 1)
```

Any assistance would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

Flutter navigate one page to another page by using this

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>SecondRoute()),
  );
```

to see parameter pass from one page to another page

[Passing data](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

Comment: Thanks for your response but the above code is to open an app and pass to another page

Comment: In android, putExtra method will pass parameters between two activity. This concept use in flutter by passing data, which provide the link